# Append text to equation tags

Tags: amsmath, tags

I want to *append* the current section to equation tags, even if I use the `\tag` command to override it. I would guess this entails creating some custom command like `\appendtag`.

I know I can use `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` to add the section number to the tags. I actually use
`\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}--\arabic{equation}}`, because I prefer a dash over the dot.
However, if I use the `\tag` command, I override the whole tag (as in equation (Ex) below). What I wish to do is just append some text, so that the equation tag reads (1-Ex).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}--\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

We have an untagged equation like
\begin{equation}
    y = X\beta + \varepsilon,
\end{equation}
with a second untagged equation like
\begin{equation}
    E(\varepsilon_i | X) = 0. \tag{Ex}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In `(1-Ex)`, the number would be the section number? And is it  always the same text that would be appended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\arabic{section}--\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{First}

We have an untagged equation like
\begin{equation}
    y = X\beta + \varepsilon,
\end{equation}
with a second untagged equation like
\begin{equation}
    E(\varepsilon_i | X) = 0. \tag{Ex}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\tag` to achieve any format, and `\label` and `\ref` will reproduce them.  The only difference is that `\tag` turns off the automatic `\stepcounter{equation}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

We have an untagged equation like
\begin{equation}\stepcounter{equation}
    y = X\beta + \varepsilon, \tag{\thesection-\theequation}
\end{equation}
with a second untagged equation like
\begin{equation}\stepcounter{equation}
    E(\varepsilon_i | X) = 0. \tag{\theequation-Ex}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]